# How do you test for parallel conditions in a switch statement?

Tags: powershell

I have read in different sources that the SWITCH statement yields better performance than multiple IF statements. I have the following blocks of IF statements which have parallel conditions. Is it possible to do this in a SWITCH block?

```
if (($statusCode -eq "OK:") -and ($messageOutput)) {

    $returnValue = 0 
    return $returnValue
}

if (($statusCode -eq "WARNING:") -and ($messageOutput)) {

    $returnValue = 1
    return $returnValue
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: -1, a little research would answer your question. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730937.aspx

Comment: @Raf - not sure that link addresses the question. It's not about _how_ to write a switch statement, it concerns using a switch with multiple conditions.

Comment: If you were truly looking for multiple conditions I think you could do `switch($true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a constant here which is `$messageOutput`, so the conditions aren't really parallel. You could do:

```powershell
if($messageOutput) {
  switch ($statusCode) {
    "OK:" { 0 }
    "WARNING:" { 1 }
    default { 1 }
  }
}
```

This would be more efficient as you don't need to recheck each variable for each condition.

Comment: Thank you arco444. Nice improvement. I will run performance benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

Arco444 has the best answer for this particular case. However it is worth noting that it is possible to have multiple conditions in a `switch` block. In case another SO user finds their way here:

```
Switch($true){
    (($statusCode -eq "OK:") -and ($messageOutput)){"Alright"}
    (($statusCode -eq "WARNING:") -and ($messageOutput)){"Not Alright"}
    default{"Something Wrong"}
}
```

The conditions are all evalutaed based on if the are `$true`. The `default` would catch if none of the other conditions are true.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to approach multiple conditions with a Switch:

```
Switch ([string][int[]]($Condition1,$Condition2))
{
  '1 1' { 'Both conditions are true' }
  '1 0' { 'Condition1 is true and Condition2 is false' }
  '0 1' { 'Condition1 is false and Condition2 is true' }
  '0 0' { 'Both conditions are false' }
}
```

Comment: I Will have to try this. Thanks.